# Decryption not working using Symmetric Key (Crypto Kit) ios

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, apple-cryptokit

I am storing SymmetricKey in Keychain which is shared between App and App Share Extension.
When I run the app encryption/decryption happens properly using the key, however, when I do decryption of text from App Extension using same key it throws following error

> CryptoKit.CryptoKitError.authenticationFailure

decryption logic

```
func decrypt(_ value : Any?) -> Data? {
    let value = value as! any DataProtocol
    
    do {
        let sealedBox = try ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: value)
        let data = try ChaChaPoly.open(sealedBox, using: self.symmetricKey!) 
        return data
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this link be helpful: https://tanaschita.com/20220120-symmetric-key-cryptography-with-cryptokit/